# Populating core data with predefined data?

Tags: ios, core-data

I am making an app which displays several predetermined locations on map. I've chosen to use core data to store the locations. How would I go about loading the predefined data into core data the first time the app launches? I also do not want this data to be user editable. I'm sure there is a simple way to do this, I just can't seem to figure it out. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If the data is constant, and will never change, just use separate databases.  Create your read-only database on your mac (using the simulator is best).  Then, just copy that file into your xcode resources, and have it built into the application bundle.

You can also provide a user database using the exact same model.  That way, you always have the "seed" read-only data in the bundle, and you can have a mutable database for the user's data.

Comment: This works for me too. But also a good thing is that iOS Simulator allows simulated apps to write files outside of the app's sandbox, so you can use `NSFileManager` to remove the old default DB and copy new one instead. And to know the project dir at runtime, you can add a preprocessor macro like this `PROJECT_DIR=@\"$(PROJECT_DIR)\"` in Xcode project settings.